# Core Data Relationships - setting up one relationship using multiple similar types

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationships, inverse

I am setting up Core Data in my app programmatically, and have come across an "issue" (not exactly an issue, but was wondering if anyone had found a nice way around it).

I have a base class `FormElement` (which extends `NSManagedObject`). I then extend this for various form types, e.g. `TextFieldFormElement`, `TextAreaFormElement` and `SwitchFormElement`, all extend `FormElement`. I also have a `FileAsset` class (which extends `NSManagedObject`) that stores information about files. `TextFieldFormElement` and `TextAreaFormElement` have a to-many relationship with `FileAsset` but `SwitchFormElement` does not.

I understand that I don't HAVE to sent an inverse relationship for `FileAsset`, or that I could set multiple properties in `FileAsset` as the inverse for each `FormElement` that can have a relationship with `FileAsset` (e.g. `FileAsset.textFieldElement`, `FileAsset.textAreaElement` etc).

**My question is:** has anyone found a nice workable solution for allowing an inverse relationship with any managed object of a certain type? What I really want to do is simply have one property in `FileAsset` (e.g. `FileAsset.element`) that will take any object of type `FormElement` (and so, any object that extends `FormElement`)?

Programmatically I can't see an obvious was to achieve this:
TextFieldFormElement >(one-to-many)> FileAsset
TextAreaFormElement >(one-to-many)> FileAsset
FileAsset >(one-to-one)> FormElement

Has anyone ran in to a problem like this before and found a nice solution? I guess my other option would be to ensure `FormElement` simply encompasses all possible properties for a form element and do-away with extending `FormElement`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would define `assets` as a relationship from the base class `FormElement` to `FileAsset` and make it optional. Then `element` is the inverse relationship from `FileAsset` to `FormElement`,
and can be set to an element of the base class or any derived class.